# WebRTC native sends packets very slow

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, h.264

I am working on a streaming server based on WebRTC native. For this project, I've hacked WebRTC native source code (version M60, win10 x64) to be able to feed it a pre-encoded H264 bitstream (1080p25, all frames are encoded to I frame). By default, WebRTC use 42e01f as the h264 profile, I changed it to 640032(level 5) to support 1080p. In the h264_encoder_impl.cc, I commented the encoding part, just copy the bytes from the input frame to the buffer of encoded_image_, and generated the fragment information.

It is working, but the speed of sending packets to client (Chrome) is very slow (about 2~3 fps). If I limit the feeding speed to 12 fps, it is working well.

I spent a lot of time to debug the code, what I found is the speed of sending packets in paced_sender.cc is slow, so the packet queue soon will be full, and then the encoder will be blocked and stop putting new packets into the queue until the queue is not full. I tried to remove the bitrate limitation in paced_sender.cc, the sending speed is still slow.

I also checked graphs in the Chrome WebRTC debugging page (chrome://webrtc-internals) to check if the problem could be on the receiver side, the decoding only costs about 2 ms per frame, the rate of receiving frames is about 2~3 fps, no packet is lost.

PS. the LAN is 1 Gbps.

After debugging for days, I have still no idea why the speed of sending packets is so slow. The h264 bitstream is encoded to all I frames, it could be a problem?

Any reply will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question: build WebRTC under release mode.